# For measurable function with $h(x+a)=h(x)$ almost everywhere exists $g=h$ where it holds for all $x$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Excuse the question, I found it hard to word it compactly.**

Say I have $a \in \mathbb{R}^n\backslash \{0\}$ and  $h:  \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow  \mathbb{R} $ and $$h(x+a)=h(x)$$ for almost all $x$ ( i.e. up until a zero measure set ) and where h is measurable.

I want to show then, that there exists $ g:  \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow  \mathbb{R} $ and $g(x+a)=g(x)$ for ALL $x$ and also $h=g$ almost everywhere.

**I'm not looking for a solution**, but I've never done such an exercise before and I'm not sure how to approach it. So I'm thinking we just have to define a set first, i.e. $A:= \{x \in\mathbb{R}^n | h(x) \neq h(x+a)\}$

and then a function $$
g(x)= 
\begin{cases}
h(x) &x \not\in A \\
h(x+a) &x \in A
\end{cases}
$$

and actually, shouldn't $g$ have all the wanted properties now? I don't think the exercise is that simple and I do think I need to use the measurability of $f$ somewhere, but I don't see why or how.

**Is my approach correct? If not,  how can I approach it?**

Comment: Why is $g(x+a) = g(x)$ for $x \in A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your definition of $g(x)$ we have $g(x)\ne g(x+a)$ whenever $x+a\in A.$ Namely, if $x+a\in A,$ then $g(x+a)=h(x+2a)\ne h(x+a).$ Now there are two cases:
$$x\in A\implies g(x)=h(x+a);$$
$$x\notin A\implies g(x)=h(x)=h(x+a);$$
either way, $g(x)=h(x+a)\ne g(x+a).$

Here's how I would do it:

Let $A=\{x:h(x)\ne h(x+a)\}.$ Define
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{ if }\ x\in A+\{na:n\in\mathbb Z\},\\
h(x)&\text{ if }\ x\notin A+\{na:n\in\mathbb Z\}.
\end{cases}$$
Then $g(x)=h(x)$ almost everywhere because $A$ has measure zero, and so does $A+\{na:n\in\mathbb Z\},$ being the union of countably many translates of $A.$

If $x\in A+\{na:n\in\mathbb Z\}$ then $x+a\in A+\{na:n\in\mathbb Z\}$ and $g(x)=0=g(x+a).$

If $x\notin A+\{na:n\in\mathbb Z\}$ then $x+a\notin A+\{na:n\in\mathbb Z\}$ and $g(x)=h(x)=h(x+a)=g(x+a).$

Comment: Can you please tell me why $A+\{na : n\in \Bbb Z\}$ has measure zero? Ain't $x=a$ is there?

Comment: I don't understand your sentence "Ain't $x=a$ is there?". For any fixed $n\in\mathbb Z$ the set $A+na$ has measure $0$ because Lebesgue measure is translation-invariant; $A+\{na:n\in\mathbb Z\}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}(A+na)$ has measure $0$ because Lebesgue measure is countably additive.